# Don't want included file content crawled

Tags: html, seo, robots.txt

I have an html file that includes a footer html file. Problem is, the footer contains a bunch of credit and copyright information that I don't want crawled - it's throwing my keyword density off.  I've "disallowed" the footer file in the robots.txt file and I've put a  tag in the head.

Is this enough to keep that part of the content from being crawled?  I've read about an iFrame trick that I'll likely try if what I've done isn't sufficient.

Geesh, you'd think there'd be an easier way to exclude blocks...

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Try using robots.txt.

To disallow all your pages use:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

To disallow some of your pages use:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /test/
Disallow: /donotcrawl.html
```

You cannot "disallow" only one part of your web page (ie: header, footer...). Its everything or nothing.

I would not use an Iframe to solve that problem. If you are using PHP, you can use the robots.txt and include() only the content you want like the footer, header or navigation menu.